# Is there a black 'dot' symbol that I can use?

Tags: symbols

I want something like this:

[image]

`gh $\blackdot$ On`

I am aware of `cdot` but this needs to be much bolder.

Comment: `\bullet` is **much** bolder.

Comment: Ot `\textbullet` in text mode.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Since `\bullet` is likely **too bold**, one can scale it to suit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}
\begin{document}
$A
\cdot A 
\sbullet A 
\sbullet[.75] A 
\bullet A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it is needed at the smaller mathstyles,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
$A
\cdot A 
\sbullet A 
\sbullet[.75] A 
\bullet A$

$\scriptstyle A
\cdot A 
\sbullet A 
\sbullet[.75] A 
\bullet A$

$\scriptscriptstyle A
\cdot A 
\sbullet A 
\sbullet[.75] A 
\bullet A$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, \bullet wasn't bold *enough*, so I did \big\bullet :)