# Bold dot and plus operator for math

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm rewriting some math equation in LaTeX, and I came across something like this: [image]

Where apparently there is something like a bullet dot operator, probably used for dot product. It's different than a regular `\cdot`. But, also the plus is different than a regular plus, it's a bit bolder and smaller. Any ideas how to write them in LaTeX?

Comment: `amssymb` has `\dotplus`.  it's not bold as you describe.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know that one, but does not correspond to the one shown in the picture.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389238/is-there-a-black-dot-symbol-that-i-can-use for more control on the dot size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the fat dot you can use `\bullet` the plus might be `\textadvanced` or a `\textsubplus`

For future reference use [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Now if you some day, even through the above question/answer set, cannot find the symbol in any existing LaTeX, you can always draw it yourself. 
I don't know if this is the proper way to do it, but here's what I came up with:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\fatterdot}{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\tikz\filldraw[black,x=2pt,y=2pt] (0,0) circle (1);}}
\newcommand{\fatplus}{\raisebox{0ex}{\tikz\filldraw[black,x=2pt,y=2pt] (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,-1) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1,0) -- cycle;}}
\begin{document}
$\Gamma\fatterdot \Delta' = \Theta \fatplus \theta \fatterdot \beta^T$
\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: Super fat plus and dot]

As you can see this is much fatter plus's and dots. They are however not nice to use with different fonts and fontsizes.

Answer (score 4):

Here I introduce `\boldify` which works across math styles and uses pdf literals to achieve the graduated bolding (thus, only works in pdflatex).  It can be used on anything in math mode.

Syntax is `\boldify[<boldness-factor>]{<argument-to-be-math-bolded>}`.  A boldness factor of `0` is no boldness.  I have set the default to `.2`.  For this MWE, I have defined also `\bcdot` and `\bplus` to define bolded `\cdot` and `+` with appropriate spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,scalerel}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\def\usecolor#1{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname\space}
\newcommand\outline[1]{\leavevmode%
  \def\maltext{#1}%
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr \thickness\space w 0 0 0 rg 0 G}{}%
  \copy\qbox%
}
\newcommand\boldify[2][.2]{%
  \def\thickness{#1}%
  \ThisStyle{\outline{$\SavedStyle#2$}}%
}
\def\bcdot{\mathbin{\boldify[1]{\cdot}}}
\def\bplus{\mathbin{\boldify[.6]{+}}}
\begin{document}
$y \boldify[0]{y} \boldify{y} \boldify[.3]{y}$

$\scriptscriptstyle y \boldify[0]{y} \boldify{y} \boldify[.3]{y}$

$\Gamma\bcdot \Lambda = \Theta \bplus \theta \bcdot \beta^T$

$\Gamma\cdot \Lambda = \Theta + \theta \cdot \beta^T$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I should add that it automaTeXly works with any font.  Thus, if I add `newtxmath` to the preamble, the result changes to

[image]