# Medium white circle like in a bulleted list

Tags: itemize

I am creating a file that mimics one of Google Doc's preselected formats. The one I selected uses a circle with no fill. However, the `$\circ$` command is too small, and `$\bigcirc$` is too big. I have also attempted the `wasysym` command `$\Circle$`, but it is too big and blurry.

Here's my current code:

```latex
... %preamble stuff

\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\(\rightarrow\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\(\medblackdiamond\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\(\medblacksquare\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{???} %where I need the circle to go

... %more preamble stuff and document
```

Comment: Depending on how thick you want the circle you could try scaling up `\circ` `\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\scalebox{1.3}{\(\circ\)}}` or scaling down `\bigcirc` `\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\scalebox{.7}{\(\bigcirc\)}}`. Note that `\scalebox` requires the `graphicx` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you load `fdsymbol`, why not use `\medblackcircle`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\( → \)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\(\medblackdiamond\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\(\medblacksquare\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\(\medblackcircle\)}%

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
        \item Level 1
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Level 2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Level 3
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Level 4
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And `\medcircle` or `\mdwhtcircle` for white! It works!

Comment: You even can change the colour, to make it more gleaming if you want! ; o)

Answer (score 1):

I have used a combination of the MWE of @Bernard and the macro of @Steven B. Segletes here to obtain different dimension of a `\bullet`:

[Is there a black 'dot' symbol that I can use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389238/is-there-a-black-dot-symbol-that-i-can-use):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\fsbullet[1][.8]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
\newcommand\ssbullet[1][.6]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
\newcommand\tsbullet[1][.4]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
\newcommand\fosbullet[1][.3]{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \scalebox{#1}{$\SavedStyle\bullet$}}}}}%
}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\(\fsbullet\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\(\ssbullet\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\(\tsbullet\)}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\(\fosbullet\)}%

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
        \item First bullet \verb|medium size:\fsbullet|
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Second bullet \verb|small size:\ssbullet|
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Third bullet \verb|tiny size:\tsbullet|
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item First bullet \verb|footnote size:\fosbullet|
                \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In addition, for example, the parameter `a` give you the dimension/size of the bullet: `\ssbullet[1][a]`.