# How may I augment or diminish the size of a symbol?

Tags: symbols

We may change the font size used in a document, but what may I do to obtain a glyph as \circ, but larger, and smaller than \bigcirc? Is there, in general, a way to regulate the size of symbols?

Comment: circ and bigcirc are two separate characters like a and A so there is no general way to constrict a character in between, but you can use something like `\scalebox{1.4}{$\circ$}` if you must. but this will scale the stroke thickness and make it look bold as well as larger

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that there are special ways, as \medcirc under txfonts.

Comment: You have Donald Arseneau's `relsize` package, which includes a `\mathlarger{…}` command.

Comment: `\medcirc` is not a special way of scaling though, it is simply another character in the font. So it has matching stroke widths but a different diamater, but to tex the relationship between circ, medcirc and bigcirc is the same as the relationship between a b and c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible it would be better to choose a symbol from the font rather than scale a symbol, the font designer will have generated circles of different diameters but with compatible stroke widths.

Unicode has a range of circles of various sizes that are available via the unicode-math package (although not all sizes are available in all fonts) This shows the circles in the Stix Two math fonts with `\circ` and `\bigcirc` shown on the second line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}

\begin{document}

\[
[\vysmwhtcircle]
[\smwhtcircle]
[\mdsmwhtcircle]
[\mdwhtcircle]
[\mdlgwhtcircle]
[\lgwhtcircle]
\]
\[
[\circ]
[\bigcirc]
\]
\end{document}
```

`unicode-math` requires luatex or xetex, but the commands are available for pdftex if you use the `stix2` package or other packages using compatble set of symbol names.

Answer (score 1):

**First Edit:** Thank you **David P. Carlisle** for your comment.

Try firstly with these functions:

```
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}
```

The **\Scale** enlarge the `math operator`
The **\Resize** scale down the `math operator`
You can consider the **Resize** as a **Scale[0<#1<1]**.

```
\newcommand{\MathOp}[5]{\mathop{\Scale[#1]{#2}}_{#3}^{#4}#5}
```

where #1 is a number (generally greater then 1) that specify how **enlarge** the `mathoperator`;
#2 is the `mathoperator` (in your case `\circ`);
#3 is the **pedex**;
#4 is the the **apex**;
#5 is the argument of `\bigcirc` (generally functions):

You'd have this for example

```
\MathOp{1.5}{\circ}{i=1}{n}{f_i}
```

Best regards

Comment: There is another function, very complicated. Would you like to have it, or my previous answer is enough? If so I'll add a new answer

Comment: I would like to see it.

Comment: where is `\Scale` defined? also why `\mathop` both `\circ` and `\bigcirc` are `\mathbin`.

Comment: why use a 5 argument form rather than use just two argument for the scale and and symbol  use `\Matop{1.5}{\circ}+{i=1}^n` if you want limits?

Comment: Because I prefer so, for me `\MathOp{}{}{}{}{}` is easier

Comment: it's harder for anyone else reading the source though, having to remember the argument order also its not  possible to omit the limits (`_{}` is not the same as having no subscript)

Comment: Something like this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389238/is-there-a-black-dot-symbol-that-i-can-use/389240#389240, done for a filled dot, could be adapted to `\circ`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn’t know you had a P in your name.

Comment: @Gaussler look at (more or less) any latex log file  for DPC :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, as you pointed out yourself in the past, to me, it’ll have to be David `\letter[script=latin,unicode=0050]` Carlisle. `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Whit this function you can define and then declare you new `math operators`. But I consille you my first answer.
Anyway in preamble

```
\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[2][1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{{#1}{#2}}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{\bigop@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\bigop@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle#2\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\bigstar}{\DOTSB\bigop{\star}}
\newcommand{\bigA}{\DOTSB\bigop[0.92]{\mathrm{A}}}
\newcommand{\bigDelta}{\DOTSB\bigop[1.05]{\Delta}}
\newcommand{\BigCircleSquare}{\bigcomp\square}
\newcommand{\bigcomp}{%
  \DOTSB
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigcomp@\relax}%
  \slimits@
}

\newcommand{\bigplus}{\DOTSB\bigop{+}}

\newcommand{\bigComplementare}{\DOTSB\bigop{\complement}}
```

I took this function from my old document but I prefer `\bigcirc` with first answer. With this function is more complex and difficult.
I gave you some examples of these functions.
Best again
Puck