# How do I globally adjust/stretch the in-between vertical spacing of items in lists only when they include display style fractions in inline math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, lists, enumerate, enumitem

Here's my MWE compiled using LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % List environment settings
\setlist[enumerate]{font={\bfseries}}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*., labelsep=0.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), align=left, leftmargin=3em, labelwidth=2.5em}
    % Resizeable \bullet symbol
\newcommand{\rbullet}[1][.75]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389240/228055
    % Custom amsthm theorem environments
\newtheoremstyle{custom}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\(\rbullet\) \bfseries} % HEADFONT
  { }         % HEADPUNCT
  {\newline} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmnote{#3 }\thmname{#1}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{custom}
\newtheorem*{problems}{Problems}
\newtheorem*{solutions}{Solutions}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}

\begin{problems}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[]
    % No. 01
    \item   Prove the following:
            \begin{enumerate}
                % (i)
                \item \(x^n - y^n = (x - y) (x^{n-1}+ x^{n-2} y + \dots + x y^{n-2} + y^{n-1})\).
                % (ii)
                \item \(x^3 + y^3 = (x + y) (x^2 - xy + y^2)\), (There is a particularly easy way to do this, using \textbf{(iv)}, and it will show you how to find a factorization for \(x^n + y^n\) whenever \(n\) is odd.)
            \end{enumerate}
    % No. 02
    \item What is wrong with the following ``proof''? Let \(x = y\). Then
    \begin{align*}
        x^2 &= xy, \\ 
        x^2 - y^2 &= xy - y^2, \\ 
        (x + y) (x - y) &= y (x - y), \\ 
        x + y &= y, \\ 
        2y &= y, \\ 
        2 &= 1.
    \end{align*}
    % No. 03
    \item   Prove the following:
            \begin{enumerate}
                % (i)
                \item \(\dfrac{a}{b} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{ad + bc}{bd}\), if \(b\), \(d \neq 0\).
                % (ii)
                \item \(\left.\dfrac{a}{b} \,\middle/\, \dfrac{c}{d}\right. = \dfrac{ad}{bc}\), if \(b\), \(c\), \(d \neq 0\).  
                % (iii)
                \item If \(b\), \(d \neq 0\), then \(\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d}\) if and only if \(ad = bc\). Also determine when \(\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{b}{a}\).
            \end{enumerate}
    % No. 04
    \item   Find all numbers \(x\) for which
            \begin{enumerate}
                % (i)
                \item \(\dfrac{1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{1 - x} > 0\).
                % (ii)
                \item \(\dfrac{x - 1}{x + 1} > 0\).
            \end{enumerate}
    % No. 05
    \item   Prove the following:
            \begin{enumerate}
                % (i)
                \item If \(a < b\) and \(c < d\), then \(a + c < b + d\).
                % (ii)
                \item If \(a < b\), then \(-b < -a\).
            \end{enumerate}
    % No. 06
    \item   \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
                % (a)
                \item Prove that if \(0 \leq x < y\), then \(x^n < y^n\),\(n = 1, 2, 3, \dots\)
                % (b)
                \item Prove that if \(x < y\) and \(n\) is odd, then \(x^n < y^n\).
            \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{problems}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When using the `enumitem` package, I am generally fine with the default vertical `sep` values in lists but I find it to be a bit narrow or tight when there are display style fractions in inline math mode, i.e., `\dfrac`s included in the `\item`s. For example, I find the in-between vertical spacing starting from **3**, then **3(i)**, **3(ii)**, **3(iii)**, **4**, **4(i)**, **4(ii)**, and ending at **5** to be not enough for my personal taste. The rest is fine, though.

My question is:
***How do I globally adjust/stretch the in-between vertical spacing of items in lists only when they include display style fractions in inline math mode?***

Preferably without manually adding options to each and every single `enumerate` environments that include display style fractions in inline math mode and without globally affecting the vertical spacing and `sep` values of the other `enumerate` environments that don't include display style fractions in inline math mode as to not the overstretch the entire document's length. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I come up with. Instead of figuring out whether there is `\dfrac` somewhere in the list and then change the sep, you can locally redefine `\dfrac` itself, so that it is a bit "taller" that would simulate that additional space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{font={\bfseries}}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*., labelsep=0.5em}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), align=left, leftmargin=3em, labelwidth=2.5em}

\makeatletter
\let\enumcopy\enumerate
\let\endenumcopy\endenumerate
\let\olddfrac\dfrac
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{
    \renewcommand{\dfrac}[2]{
        \olddfrac{##1}{##2}
        \ifnum\arabic{\@enumctr}>1
            \rule{0pt}{30pt}
        \fi
    }
    \enumcopy
}{
    \endenumcopy
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\dfrac{1}{2}$
    \item $\dfrac{1}{2}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation:

First of all, I make a copy a of `enumerate` environment by doing

```
\let\enumcopy\enumerate
\let\endenumcopy\endenumerate
```

this works because each environment in latex is actually two macros `\ENV` and `endENV`. Afterwards you can redefine `enumerate` using itself.

```
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{
    \enumcopy
}{
    \endenumcopy
}
```

Now it's only the matter of placing the redefined `\dfrac` command inside `enumitem` environment definition so that it won't affect `\dfrac` anywhere else at the document.

Again we need a copy of `\dfrac` to redefine it using itself. The tallness can be increased using `\rule{0pt}{<height>}` for example.

```
\let\olddfrac\dfrac
\renewcommand{\dfrac}[2]{\olddfrac{#1}{#2}\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
```

However, if `\dfrac` will be placed in the first item of the list, additional space above might not be wanted. In order to fix that you can check if it's not the first item by

```
\ifnum\arabic{\@enumctr}>1
    <code>
\fi
```

where `\@enumctr` is a counter of the current level enumerate environment.

Also note that you have to escape `#1` and `#2` by adding an extra `#` if you are using it inside another `\renew...`

---

If you set the width of the rule to `1pt` for example

```
\rule{1pt}{30pt}
```

you will see how exactly it works

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!